# API URL with http protocol is not working in productive

Tags: reactjs, http, url, protocols

I'm using the API **http://challenge-react.alkemy.org/** and is working perfectly in the dev environment. But when I deploy it and go to the link that netlify provides to me, I have this message:
***Mixed Content: The page at 'https://monumental-banoffee-379a6e.netlify.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://challenge-react.alkemy.org/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS***.

The thing is that if I add the http**S**://challenge-react.alkemy.org/ to the API URL, the link crashes and is not working (apparently only work with the **http** protocol. How can I fix this?

I add this meta tag into the HTML but is not working: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests" />`

Answer (score -1):

If an API URL with HTTP protocol is not working in a productive environment, consider switching to HTTPS. Many production environments enforce secure connections. Update the URL to use HTTPS, and ensure that the server supports it. If the issue persists, check server logs for errors and ensure the API is correctly configured for HTTPS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).